# Read All Items From a Queue After Interval, Run Task For Each

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx). An external process adds items to this queue (JSON request bodies). Every minute, I want to take all of the items from the queue and "resubmit" each. I have two methods describe what I am trying to do; however, what I haven't figured out how to do is how to run the `Timer` callback until the queue is empty (see below).

```
public void InitializeRequestResubmission()
{
    _timer = new Timer(e => _ResubmitRemoteRequest(), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

Here is the callback definition.

```
private void _ResubmitRequest()
{
    RequestModel requestModel = null;
    if (!_service.PendingResuestQueue.TryDequeue(out requestModel)) return;
    var task = _service.RetrieveWrappedTask(requestModel);
    task.Start();   // notice use of TPL
}
```

As you can see, I am using the Task Parallel Library (TPL). Conceivably, I could run the callback body in a loop; however, if it is possible to speed this up by adding in threads (preferably tasks), that would be great.

Is a loop the best way to empty the queue? Or, is there a way to do this concurrently?

Comment: If you are not doing that in a loop, how do you get all items from queue?

Comment: Have a look at [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @sstan `ConcurrentQueue` is default implementation for `BlockingCollection`

Comment: @Evk I get that. But, from what you see above, is that thread safe? I am new to TPL.

Comment: use  `GetConsumingEnumerable()` with a foreach loop. so `foreach( whatever in YourQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()` This allows you to pull out elements from the queue and it blocks when the queue is empty.

Comment: @Thomas: `ConcurrentQueue` is the default backing ***collection type*** for `BlockingCollection`, not the default ***implementation***.  Have a closer look at `BlockingCollection`.  You'll see it offers a nice API to do everything you need.

Comment: @sstan thanks. That just cleared up like ten different things for me! I've got some code to change!

Comment: @Thomas if you use BlockingCollection - why do you need any timers at all? Just process items as they arrive (in a dedicated thread).

Comment: @Evk the timer is a specification I am trying to meet, i.e. "resubmitting all failed requests after one minute".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@sstan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4955425/sstan)'s comment, I went back and had a look at the [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation. I've changed the callback body (and collection), accordingly.

The collection is now defined as:

```
// Default collection type is a ConcurrentQueue
public BlockingCollection<RequestModel> PendingResuestQueue { get; set; }
```

In the callback, I am then doing this:

```
RequestModel requestModel = null;

while (_service.PendingResuestQueue.TryTake(out requestModel))
{
    var task = _service.RetrieveWrappedTask(requestModel);
    task.Start();
}
```

`TryTake(T)` can fail for a number reasons, I am assuming. Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287184(v=vs.110).aspx), it states:

> If the collection is empty, this method immediately returns false.

I am assuming `false` can be returned for failure, as well. If that is the case, that is okay as I am going to re-run the task on one-minute intervals.

**EDIT**:

It also looks like on might be able to use the [`GetConsumingEnumerable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx) method, here:

```
foreach (var request in _service.PendingResuestQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    var task = // ...
    task.Start();
}
```

Comment: One problem with this approach is if you have a lot of items in queue, processing of all of them will start at the same time, using dedicated thread for each one. You most likely don't want this, instead you want to limit that to process in X parallel threads.

Comment: @Evk yes, the latter is what I am after. What would I change, here? If you are able to post an answer with a better solution, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The goal is not clear still. You collect failed requests in queue and retry all items from that queue every minute. But there might be requests that failed say 1 second ago, it just so happened that your minute has passed. How does that matches specification?

Comment: I am trying to collect failed requests over a minute period and then resubmit those requests. So, process would be collect for a minute -> run collection -> collect for another minute --> run collection. 

There could be a period without any failed requests. 

The collecting should never stop; but the resubmissions should be limited to those that were collected over the preceeding minute. 

Maybe I should add in a pause trigger to the collection? e.g. while the resubmission task in running (over a period of seconds), I am preventing additions?

Comment: I think you don't need BlockingCollection at all, just use simple List. On failure lock over it and add item. In callback of your timer, lock over it and _copy all items_ from it to local vartiable (for example with ToArray() call). Then release lock and resubmit all items. Those locks will have no impact on perfomance at all (just don't hold a lock when you resubmit - first copy to local variable).

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113060/discussion-between-thomas-and-evk).